# Rails website speed seems low

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

Hi I am Ruby on Rails beginner,Our Rails application is hosted in amazon web services. For last one week our website is taking long time to respond. This happens only in a particular browser that means if site slow in Firefox and if I go to chrome in same system it works well and vice verse.I  don't know where are the places to look up to solve the issue. Please suggest me the way to find and rectify the problem causing places.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Log everything, analyze it to find where you're having problems.

At a 10,000ft level, consider looking at Newrelic or Datadog; both services specialize in "Application Performance Monitoring", which can be helpful in finding where your site is slow. They will give you average times for your app's actions, and can provide breakdowns of time spent in application code, IO blocking, and garbage collection.

Once you have a general location of code that is taking too long to run, consider using something like [request_profiler](https://github.com/justinweiss/request_profiler) to profile your slow actions and determine what exactly in them is slow.

These are just a few places you might start; without instrumenting your application, you aren't going to be able to make any headway with it.

Comment: Hi chris , My website doesn't seems slower in all browsers at all times. It will works normally but in some times in particular browsers it took long time to respond

Comment: That's why you need logging and monitoring, to find out why it's slow when it's slow.